# Jquery.get not working with ssl

Tags: javascript, jquery, ssl

I recently added an SSL certificate to my website and since then some of the jquery functions are no longer working. Specifically jquery.get

Example:

```
function getBfeForm() {
        jQuery.get('/wp-admin/admin.php/?page=booking.multiuser.5.3/wpdev-booking.phpwpdev-booking-resources&tab=availability&wpdev_edit_avalaibility=<?php echo key($_REQUEST['avail']); ?>/', function(data) {
            jQuery('[name="avail['+<?php echo key($_REQUEST['avail']); ?>+']"]').removeClass('spinner').val('Edit Availability');
            if (data) {
                jQuery('#availHolder .holder').html(jQuery(data).find('.inside'));
                jQuery('#availHolder .holder').prepend('<div id="popHeader"><a title="Close" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close" href="javascript:;">Close</a></div>');
                jQuery('#availHolder').hide();
                jQuery('#availHolder').appendTo(jQuery('[data-resource="<?php echo key($_REQUEST['avail']); ?>"]').find('tr.clean td'));
                jQuery('#availHolder').slideDown(500);
            }
        });
    }
```

This function works fine with http but when SSL is activated and https used the function no longer calls the file. I have seen other comments on here saying the lack of trailing slashes is the issue, but I believe I have added trailing slashes correctly now and it still doesn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: I added `alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);` to the function to see what data was actually being served. It appears the wordpress log in page is being called rather than the file specified in the function. I have tested this on a duplicate site without SSL and it calls the correct file. Does this mean the SSL is not allowing a link to wp-admin files?

Comment: can you open that url in browser on https? Have you inspected request in browser dev tools network for clues? Just saying it *"doesn't work"* doesn't tell us much

Comment: The url is behind a log in and any attempt to load the url directly in a browser seems to log the user out and redirect to the log in page. Unfortunately nothing is showing up in the javascript console either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and posting the answer here for anyone else who is implementing an SSL certificate. The issue was the custom login page we have. We are using the wp_signon function and we had `$user_verify = wp_signon( $login_data, false );`. This should be `$user_verify = wp_signon( $login_data, true );` - setting the value to 'true' creates a secure cookie. If the cookie is not secure, each time a user tries to access wp-admin files they are logged out and required to log in again.

For details check the [wordpress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon) for `wp_signon`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows and have a local certificate installed in IIS then try access the site with fully qualified name of the computer

[computer_name].[domain_name]

For example: [ox-pchris11].[companyname.com] where ox-pchris11 is the computer name and companyname.com is the domain name.

if you access the site as localhost it will show a error page which will ask permission to continue.

Comment: No local certificate and it's not on localhost. The website is on a live server.